# Return multiple items from a table

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, array-formulas, structured-references

I have an Excel file with two sheets. In "Sheet 1" I have data that is formatted as a table. It has three columns:

```
MyData[Name]         MyData[Month]         MyData[sales]
```

On "Sheet 2" I want to select multiple items from `MyData` that match a criterion (that `MyData[Name]` = `John`).

I have found this great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp7I5u1MqiM) that explains how to do this, with an array formula that combines INDEX, SMALL, ROWS and IFs. The problem is that in the video they use regular ranges with hard-coded row numbers.

Is there a way to do this selection, but to use column names instead of the hard-coded ranges?

Comment: what is your data sample like? give an example of what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though I am not sure about relative referencing using structured references, so offer two array formulae, assuming your selection criterion (eg `John`) is in A1 of your second sheet:

In B1:

```
=IF(ROWS(A$1:A1)<=COUNTIF(MyData[[#All],[Name]],$A$1),INDEX(MyData[[#All],[Month]],SMALL(IF(MyData[[#All],[Name]]=$A$1,ROW(MyData[[#All],[Name]])-ROW(MyData[[#Headers],[Name]])+1),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")
```

In C1:

```
 =IF(ROWS(B$1:B1)<=COUNTIF(MyData[[#All],[Name]],$A$1),INDEX(MyData[[#All],[sales]],SMALL(IF(MyData[[#All],[Name]]=$A$1,ROW(MyData[[#All],[Name]])-ROW(MyData[[#Headers],[Name]])+1),ROWS(C$1:C1))),"")
```

both entered in second sheet with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and copied down until no values are returned.

Answer (score 1):

You generally do not require all of the [structured table references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E) that come with point and select on table objects as you build a formula. Much like the verbose code produced by the macro recorder, the auto-generated table range references are meant to handle a variety of situations and some pieces may not be necessary or desired.

[image: Structured Table Lookup Multiple]

The standard formulas in G4:H4 are,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MyData[Month], AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(MyData)-ROW(MyData[#Headers])/(MyData[Name]=$F$4), ROW(1:1))), "")
=IFERROR(INDEX(MyData[Sales], AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(MyData)-ROW(MyData[#Headers])/(MyData[Name]=$F$4), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

This uses the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) in its [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) form to force an error on any non-matching rows and subsequently ignore the errors when retrieving the multiple matching items.

¹<sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in previous versions.</sub>